# Adjust label based on Text given in Text view in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, uilabel

I am working on **Photo Editing App** and i am trying to adjust label Based on Text given in Text View . I have tried Lots of code but it did not work for me. i want to add Label on Image Which is based on text given in my textview as shown in Image given below.[image] I am unable to set width and height of label based on textview's text. I have Tried Following code. Some one please help.

```
let newWidth: CGFloat = CGFloat(txtView.text.boundingRect(with: txtView.frame.size, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,  context: nil).size.width)
let Label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: newWidth, height: 100))
imgView?.addSubview(Label)
```

I have also tried

```
var maximumLabelSize = CGSize(width: 296, height: FLT_MAX)
var expectedLabelSize: CGSize = yourString.size(withFont: yourLabel.font, constrainedTo: maximumLabelSize, lineBreakMode: yourLabel.lineBreakMode)
//adjust the label the the new height.
var newFrame: CGRect = yourLabel.frame
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height
yourLabel.frame = newFrame
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are doing. Do you have a `UIImageView`, and you want to show a `UILabel` on top of it? Should the text be centered? Should it cover the entire image, or just a portion? I suggest you show a picture of what you want as a result.

Comment: @DonMag Please check my updated question.

Comment: the screenshot you provided I guess it's from **JLStickerTextView**. you want to add label onto a picture, this JLStickerTextView library is made to do so. I am using this library for video editing app. check the example provided by the author with the library

Comment: hey @ImrulKayes , I have also tried this library but there is Build time error I have already Added issue in it https://github.com/luiyezheng/JLStickerTextView/issues/16

Comment: @KhushbuDesai, you have to edit that library cause its written in an earlier version of Swift (probably 1.2). Follow the Xcode's instructions and eradicate errors manually (which I have done).

Comment: yes @ImrulKayes i have solved al that errors and My issue is solved now. i am going to upload that error free library soon on github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my issue using **JLStickerTextView** but in this repository its not compatible for **Swift 3.0**  so i have made changes in project and you can find out Working Project without any errors from her https://github.com/khush004/StickerView/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

```
func calcheight(strin:String) -> CGFloat
    {
        let label =  UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.text = strin
        label.sizeToFit()
        return label.frame.height + 2

    }
```